# How can I create a AWS APIGateway Custom Authorizer using stage variables in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform, api-gateway

I see that AWS ApiGateway now provides the ability to pass stage variables to a custom authorizer lambda in the console, by selecting the 'Request' type payload and listing the variables that should be passed though.

However, we create our AWS resources exclusively via Terraform (no manual intervention allowed), and the Terraform docs currently say:

```
type - (Optional) The type of the authorizer. TOKEN is currently the only allowed value. Defaults to TOKEN.
```

Is there some way to force the payload type to be 'REQUEST' programmatically, and pass in stage variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do this through Terraform, despite what the docs say.

Just set the type to REQUEST, and pass the stage variables (and/or headers, and/or query strings) in a comma-separated list like this: "method.request.header.SomeHeaderName,method.request.querystring.SomeQueryStringName,stageVariables.SomeStageVariableName" etc:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "api-gateway-auth" {
  ...
  type            = "REQUEST"
  identity_source = "method.request.header.SomeHeaderName,method.request.querystring.SomeQueryStringName,stageVariables.SomeStageVariableName"
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. It might be worth raising a [pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pulls) to update the documentation if you are happy to do that?

Comment: Thanks - I'd looked for the docs on Github before writing this but couldn't find them. PR raised.